# Millitary command « Demi-tour »

Tags: vocabulaire

Is « demi-tour » the correct   French command to make a soldier turn around 180 degrees?

Comment: Yes. But it's a turn for 200 grad or 180 degrees or pi rad.

Comment: @Toto. Merci. Quant à « Grad » j'ai malheureux pris le mot allemagne, ma langue maternelle.

Comment: On entend aussi souvent (dans les films en tout cas, je n'ai pas fait l'armée) "Demi-tour gauche" ou "Demi-tour droite" pour indiquer dans quel sens tourner.

Comment: @Laurent. Très bon. Je veux correcter les commandes dans mon texte.

Comment: In addition: Correcter => Corriger; Commandes => Ordres

Comment: Très bon => Très bien.

Answer (score 2):

Bonjour,

Je ne suis pas militaire, toutefois, wikipedia indique qu'en ordre serré, l'ordre permettant de retourner un régiment (180°) est :

> Demi-tour … droite !

Ceci est le mouvement consistant à inverser le sens de marche *à l'arrêt*.
Je note que "Demi-tour .... gauche !" n'existe pas (c'est assez conforme à mon préjugé car on doit commencer le mouvement au moment où "droite" est dit, ce qui est incompatible avec la "surprise" laissée par le sens non annoncé !).

> Deux fois à droite (ou à gauche)… Marche !

Cet ordre (que je ne connaissais pas) consiste à inverser le sens de marche, *en marche*. Je ne l'ai jamais constaté, ça me semble périlleux, mais apparemment, c'est réglementaire :-)

Sources :
https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordre_serr%C3%A9#Mouvements_de_pied_ferme

## English answer

The proper order, *when stopped* is :

> Demi-tour … droite !

the "..." is a silence of about a second.

There is such an order in "Jungle Book" (Walt Disney), if you want to hear a French voice telling such an order :-)

The other proper order, *when walking* is :

> Deux fois à droite (ou à gauche)… Marche !

Comment: "À droite" en marche : quand on arrive à un carrefour, on change de voie sur sa droite ; en marche à droite ou à gauche est sur une base de 90° … en principe … car cela fonctionne aussi quand ils arrivent à une patte-d'oie, et place de l’Étoile autour de l’arc de triomphe "Troisième à droite" sera la troisième avenue rencontrée. utile pour le 14 juillet :-)